# Is there a way to copy the contents of a String in Eclipse using a keyboard shortcut or menu item?

Tags: java, eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

Let's say I have this string:

```
String strName = "aaa" +
+ "bbb" +
+ "ccc" + 
+ "ddd" + 
+ "eee";
```

Let's say I have a lot of those type of strings, like tens of thousands. But let's say there are several times as many which I *don't* want to touch.

I need to grab the contents of these strings **quicker than selecting the string and copying it**, but since I need to manually determine whether or not these strings are the right ones, automating this process would take a long time and be prone to a lot of errors.

What I *want* to do is take the contents:

```
"aaa" +
+ "bbb" +
+ "ccc" + 
+ "ddd" + 
+ "eee";
```

And insert them into my clipboard with, hopefully, either a keyboard shortcut or menu item. The formatting varies constantly, so I'm just looking to copy what's between `"";` without having to select it manually.

Is there a keyboard shortcut or menu item which can insert the contents of a string into the clipboard?

Here's how I'd expect it to work:

```
String strName =
          ^------ select this, hit keyboard shortcut, contents are copied

   v----------clipboard now has this data:
"aaa" +
+ "bbb" +
+ "ccc" + 
+ "ddd" + 
+ "eee";
```

**Assume automation of this process using third party tools outside of the editor, and find/replace, are not allowed. I've already written a program, and cannot use it.** I'm looking for an in-editor shortcut, or menu item.

Comment: how about to copy all the data into a notepad++ for example and then replacing all unwanted content with " " ?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm currently doing. Just wondering if there is a keyboard shortcut to copy the contents automatically.

Comment: Have you thought about running the programm and printing the variable values?

Comment: @lupz That would take a lot more time. They're spread out across many different projects, and many of them require access to things I do not have access to, so the program(s) will not run.

Comment: a) if the strings are constants, create a `main()` method that prints them. b) Hover your mouse over them and it will show a focusable tooltip with the value; selecti it and copy it

Comment: @TassosBassoukos Regarding main(), that won't work very well because of inaccessible `static String` return values. Regarding b), is there something I need to do to enable that? It doesn't work for me.

Comment: I'm not sure how realistic it is; it seems fairly complex to determine that an String's static value can be reconstructed from arbitrary numbers of + operators. It would have to handle the case where it encounters an operand that is NOT a literal string (ie, a variable or expression). Eclipse's JDT model of code could make it a little easier, but that means writing a plugin.

Comment: I just stumbled uppon the [scrapbook feature of eclipse jdt](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/concepts/cscrapbook.htm). Basically you can throw in some expressions and run/evaluate them without a debugging context. You have to copy the string literals you are interested in to a scrapbook, select the expression and inspect it (there is a keyboard shortcut for inspect. It's [cmd]+[i] here)

Answer (score 2):

(Obviously a lot depends on the details of what you want to do, which you don't explain.)

I have found that for jobs for which one wants *some* automation ("tens of thousands" of items) but also need to retain *some* human eyeballs ("I need to manually determine...") **Regular Expressions** are often helpful. Eclipse's "Find/Replace" (`Ctrl+F`) dialog helps you to find occurrences belonging to a certain pattern, then still leaves you the choice of changing it (<kbd>Replace/Find</kbd> vs. <kbd>Find</kbd> (without replacing) ). Eclips doesn't have much help on regular expressions, but you can look at the [Javadoc for `Pattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for a fairly thorough manpage. Or look at various tutorials (google), but be aware that there are different versions and you want the one that is used in Java.

If your strings do not have a nice pattern you can use, what can maybe help is to mark each positive OR negative line's first character with some character that is not used (much) in the code, e.g. `~` or `#`. Then you can easily match those lines with a regexp. For instance, once those lines are marked, you can remove all lines matching (or NOT matching) that starting pattern, by replacing them with an empty string.

It might also be helpful to make copies of your files or extract just the lines you are interested in to a new file, then work on those copies, so that you don't mess up your source code files - again depending on what you need to do.

There are of course other text editors available that also do (different dialects of) regular expressions, like [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) and [Notetab](http://www.notetab.com/) (Windows environments) - sometimes the small differences in dialect are useful so I open my text in the required editor to do something Eclipse doesn't allow me to do.

Comment: This is likely the only useful answer to the actual question, but I feel obliged to point out http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/223634/187751

Comment: Thank you, fr13d. I've already done everything you suggested, and more. I am not allowed to automate this process, and it must be done manually. A simple keyboard shortcut or menu item would help alleviate my pain. =p

Comment: :-) Right, @E-Riz. If you only have a hammer, everything looks like a nail.

Comment: Sorry @MarkBuffalo. You do seem to have some crappy constraints on you regarding what is deemed automation and what not (helicopter supervisor?).

`Ctrl+Shitf+L` shows you all the standard shortcuts (as I guess you know). You could conceivably add your own (I have never), from the tutorials I doubt you could make them do anything more than what's built in. Your requirement seems fairly esoteric, I've needed to do some more standard things (my opinion) that are also not catered for. Write a plugin for Eclipse?? (probably will be viewed as automation too...)

Comment: I think writing a plugin would be great, but at this time there is no time dedicated to that.

Answer (score -2):

Copy the expression from the first `"` to the last one, and pass it to the following program as the input:

```
perl -npe 's/^([+] )?"(.*)"( +[+] *|;)[\r\n]*$/$2/g';
```

Note, you might need an additional (or two) blank lines at the end of the quotes.

Edit: this will not unescape escape sequences.

Comment: What do you mean by, "pass it to the following program as the input"? Is there a perl command in Eclipse that I'm unaware of? Or are you expecting me to run perl?

Comment: Ah, so you're on Windows. Sorry man. But you can write a Java program that does that for you.

Comment: Yeah, I could write one that does it for me, agreed. What I'm really looking for is a keyboard shortcut or menu item that will allow me to get the contents by selecting the string name.

Comment: Just hover your name over the field or variable name.

Comment: That would be excellent if it worked. Unfortunately, it does not. It only displays the name of the string, and the package path. No other contents exist. How would I enable what you suggested, then?